# ScrollView with TextView with HTML inside another scrollView with clickable links, does not work

Tags: android, html, scrollview, textview, android-scrollview

I have a scrollView , now I need to have a small scrollable textView inside this scrollView. I was able to do it with the below code :

```
 scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.childScrollView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
    childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

// Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
// child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now textView scrolls inside child scrollview. I need to show HTML in this textView with clickable links. Now as soon as I give the property

```
txtView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

the textView stops scrolling. I need scrolling and clickable links inside the textview.

How to change the above code so that I can keep the scrolling of the textView as well apply the *setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())* on the textView.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I could not find a solution to the above problem. 
I solved my problem by using WebView instead of TextView inside a scrollView.

Now to make the make webview scroll inside ScrollView ,I used the same code which I used earlier  and the only change I did was to use ***WebView as ChildView*** for the ParentScrollView like this ;

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

// Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
// child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

This way I was able to scroll the textview (which is now inside webview) inside a scrollView.